# Inverse image Weil divisor on a toric variety as a Cartier divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, toric-varieties, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X$ be a normal toric variety over an algebraically closed field and let $D$ be a torus invariant (prime) divisor. Assume $\pi\colon \tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is a toric resolution of singularities such that the support of $\pi^{-1}D$ is a Cartier divisor. (This can always be done by starting with a resolution of $X$ and then blowing up the irreducible components of the inverse image of $D$.)

**Question**: is the scheme theoretic inverse image $\pi^{-1} D$ also a Cartier divisor? And if so, how can we determine the multiplicities of the prime divisors appearing in $\pi^{-1} D$ in terms of the fan of $X$ and $\tilde{X}$?

To me this seems like a very basic question, but I have not found anything on this in the literature on toric varieties, such as Fulton's book or the book by Cox, Little and Schenk.

If $X$ is a surface with only rational double points as singularities, then the singularities appearing are only $A_k$ singularities, so then $\pi^{-1} D$ is reduced and so equals its support. However, I am not sure whether $\pi^{-1} D$ is reduced in general for other toric varieties.